# Process binary data retrieved with UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to process binary data retrieved from a Davis weather station via their web server.

I do this using a script attached to a Google Apps Spreadsheet.

```
var lResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(lWLDataUrl);
var lContentBytes = lResponse.getAs('application/octet-stream').getBytes();
```

The data returned by Weatherlink is composed of 52 byte long records, so I slice them in a loop using :

```
var lContentObject = {};
for (var li=1; li<=lNumberOfRecords; li++) {
  var lBinaryData = lContentBytes.slice((li-1)*52, (li-1)*52+52);
  lContentObject[li] = {"binary_data": lBinaryData}; 
}
```

But the result is not what I expect.  It is difficult for me to say if the server returns faulty data (unlikely) or if I do not process it properly on my side (likely).  I should be able to turn the response into an array of unsigned 8 bit integers and decode them into a record of weather data that looks like this :

```
2015/01/01;00:30;-1,9;-1,9;-2,0;92;-3,1;1,6;W;0,80;4,8;W;-1,9;-2,1;-2,1;1031,5;0,00;0,0;0,422;0,000;18,7;42;5,5;17,4;8,14;1,2209;M;M;M;M;M;M;M;M;M;-0,6;-1,1;M;M;4;0;-0,6;-1,1;698;1;100,0;30
```

Instead, the data retrieved into `lContentBytes` shows negative numbers in the debugger, though it should not be the case.
Although the total size of the byte array returned corresponds to what I expect (the number of records * 52), the last records 'sliced' out of the byte array are filled with '-1', which should not be the case.

I did a lot of research but didn't find any solution...

Here are the headers of the response to the GET request :

- 'content-transfer-encoding':"binary",
- Connection:"keep-alive",
- 'Content-Encoding':"gzip",
- Vary:"Accept-Encoding",
- 'Content-Length':"161",
- Date:"Wed, 15 Apr 2020 20:29:13 GMT",
- 'Content-Type':"application/octet-stream"

Comment: Just in case it helps, I added the HTTP headers of the response.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue. And I cannot understand about `what I expect`. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide a sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: Tanaike, I have edited the question to try and make it clearer.  [Here](https://www.davisinstruments.com/support/weather/download/VantageSerialProtocolDocs_v261.pdf) is also a link to the document that explains how the data has been encoded before being sent in the response of the GET request.  Page 32 and 36 only.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your additional data is decoded data from the original data of `lResponse`. And `lResponse` retrieved from the URL is the binary data. You want to decode the data from `lResponse`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct.  And to decode the data from lResponse, I need to be able to see it as unsigned 8 bit integers.  And I do not find the way to do this is Javascript (well Google Apps Script actually).

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand about your goal. As next step, I'm required to know about the detail of your issue. So can you provide a sample value of `lResponse` as a file or the sample URL which can retrieve the sample value of `lResponse`? If you cannot do, please don't worry.